# How to add external javascript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, charts

I want to insert external JavaScript placed in the folder in WordPress.
if I include using script tag it shows "<" expected error 
below is my code

```
global $wpdb; 
include("/asset/php/chart4php/inc/chartphp_dist.php"); 

$p = new chartphp(); 

$p->data_sql = $wpdb->get_results("select t2.name, count(t1.id) as score from custom_status as t2 left join wpsp_ticket as t1 on t2.name =    t1.status group by t2.name");

$p->chart_type = "bar"; 

// Common Options 
$p->title = "Category Sales"; 
$p->xlabel = "Category"; 
$p->ylabel = "Sales"; 

 $color = array("#1AAF5D","#F2C500","#F45B00","#8E0000","#0E948C"); 
 $p->color = $color[rand(0,4)]; 

 $out = $p->render('c1');
```

Tried including js files

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_search' );
wp_register_script( 'chartphp', plugins_url('/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
```

wp_enqueue_script( 'chartphp' );

Also I want to include 3 move files

```
<script src="/asset/php/chart4php/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.css">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haved added external javascript in the past by using:

```
wp_register_script( 'validation', 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'validation' );
```

From what I can see, [you are not enqueuing the script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) after you register it in WP.

Also double check your plugin url path is correct as an extra measure.

Comment: Does plugins_url('/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js' go to the file? Have you tried the path in the browser to see if it links?

Also are you still getting the "<" expected error?

Comment: how to check that its gng to url are not.yes still getting error

Comment: I would echo plugins_url('/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js', __FILE__);

Then see if you can go to that url. If not, you might not be linking to the JS file correctly.

If that works, you'll need to do a little more debugging as the screenshot you have added does not tell us where the error is breaking from.

Comment: Even I am bit confused from where I am getting error....if I add other script also same error...

Comment: if i do echo it says page not found error  echo plugins_url('/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js', FILE);

Comment: Sorry the comment stripped out some code. Try this echo plugins_url('/asset/php/chart4php/chartphp.js');

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to include scripts in WordPress is using [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

If you previously registered the script you can simply reference it:

> You could either link a script with a handle previously registered using the [wp_register_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) function, or provide this function with all the parameters necessary to link a script.

Note that if you include default scripts such as jQuery in the dependencies parameter, you don't need to register and/or enqueue them separately.